# Discrete Wavelet Transform (DWT) and Stationary Wavelet Transform (SWT) in Java

Tags: java, image, wavelet-transform, dwt

I want to apply DWT and SWT to images in Java but can't find code, pseudocode or libraries for that. Until now, I only found existing code in other languages like C, C++ or Python but I need it in Java and I'm not able to change the code from one to another language on my own.

Does anyone know a library or another way I could use to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Detailed description of the problem:
I want to apply DWT or SWT to an image and then do some further calculations with specific DWT/SWT subbands e.g. applying Discrete Cosine Function (DCT) to the LL-subband. If possible, I want to work with BufferedImages.

Comment: Hello, you may need to visit Help Center and to learn [how to ask good question at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, [this query](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+implementation+stationary+wavelet+transform) immediately provides links to the requested Java implementations at CodeProject and GitHub

Comment: If I had found an answer (e.g. on google), I wouldn't have asked this question here. Your link doesn't help. If you don't want to help but just mock people who don't know how to solve a problem then don't answer at all. Thanks for nothing.